# Need to Compile the SSCC file to CSS through angular ts code (not in cli)

Tags: angular, sass, build, compilation

in my code i have multiple SCSS file, i made the component to download each SCSS downloadable. for that i need to compile the selected SCSS file while i create blob with the string '**@import 'filename';@import 'file2name'**;. compiling through the angular click function (compile code '**npm run build-css**')

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding, **you can not** do that in browser. You need some **sass compiler** that will run on machine (**some server**) that can convert the scss to css.

I will suggest to create a cloud function or create an API in your server that can convert the scss to css which can be downloaded further on frontend.